# Need suggestion- Drag and Drop in UI

Tags: java, html

Friends- I am looking for some code logic / free tools. for following requirements.

I need to add/drag image  from a folder structure(left frame) to the the central frame of a webpage.

I am saying images as a blocks.

Please help me on this.

Attaching a rough picture for the reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using HTML5 by using the following functions. But if you are not using HTML5 then you have to achieve the effect using jquery or javascript[quite complex].
I will explain all the 3 ways and provide link for implementation examples.
**1)HTML5**
If you want to drag an element, you need to set the `draggable=true` atttribute for that element, also provide `dragstart event listener`.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_drag_drop.htm
**2)Jquery** 
The same effect can be achieved with jquery very easily all you have to do is call `dragable` function on the element.
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ [click on view source to see code]
**3)javascript**
In javascript it will be done using mouse events and clicks
http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/column2/index.html

Comment: thanks. I edited the question pls look into this.

Comment: please check if the edit in answer addresses the issue

Comment: Thanks a lot war. I will try with this.